# Before Shutdown wait till saving is finished

Tags: c#, winforms, systemevent, sessionend

I have an application which logs some user data. If the users logs off the workstation it needs to save this information.

The program is a windows form c# application.

At the moment I am trying to do this by this function below and it works to 95% but not for a 100%.

```
    Application.Run(new Shutdown(_object));

    private void Shutdown_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;``
        _object.LogLogout(); //Save the logout to a file

    }
```

I tried as well the function but this didn't worked at all. And I don't understand why. Any hints? I am totally stuck here.

```
    Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnded += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndedEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnded);
    Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnding += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionEnding(SystemEvents_SessionEnding);
```

Comment: How are you calling this "Shutdown" form?  Is this your main form?

Comment: Seems a bit too late to the party.  If the data is that important, then save it in a more timely way when you do have control, such as immediately upon receipt.  You are giving up a lot of control when you try to do this in the death throes.  Having said that, when does `FormClosing` not work?

Comment: It should save the log off time and event. How should I do that earlier? I couldn't find out when it does not work. Just noticed that there is sometime no log entry of the logout

Comment: How is `LogLogout` implemented? If this starts an async thread in background mode then the application is nog gonna wait for it when shutting down.

Comment: No extra thread. It just calls an other object where the data is stored.

Comment: Why does the Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnded += new Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndedEventHandler(SystemEvents_SessionEnded); not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer the shut-down will be only stopped if the form is still visible. This wasn't the case. Therefore I solved this by doing this.

```
    private void Shutdown_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (systemShutdown)
        {
            this.Show();
            //If GUI got closed delted active entry and log off
            _object.LogLogout(); //Save the logout to a file
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
```